# Run command as common user with sudo privileges

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I'm new at linux and I'm trying to run this command as sudo:

```
sudo python script.py
```

Te command contains relative path to home, but I'm getting `/root/` as the home folder instead `/home/My_User/`

Is there a way to run the script with sudo privileges without being promoted to root as user?

Comment: There is no such thing as sudo privileges, any additional access you get is due to running as a different user. You can set the `HOME` environment variable though, and many tools will respect it

Comment: I´'m going to try that, thanks

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

sudo -E python script.py

to gain the elevated privileges but retain your user environment.

Comment: I like this one.

Comment: Just a note, that if you're going to do this make sure that script.py isn't writable by anybody except root, since if it is, the other user(s) could modify it to do *anything*. Even better would be to run the script as it's own user and change the security on the objects it works with to allow this.